# Unexpected MATLAB expression? (trying to create a function)

Tags: matlab, function, file-upload, indexing, load

```
load('matrix.mat');
userInput = input('input a value from 1-5')
DayReport = sum(matrix(:,end 2);==userInput)
```

I am trying to retrieve the number of rows in column 2 of the loaded matrix that corresponds with the userInput. However, when I try to run the code, it says that there is an error in the third line (simply, "Unexpected MATLAB expression"). Any ideas as to why this is?

---

EDIT: I found a solution, turns out i don't need the "end" or the semicolon within the sum function.

```
load('matrix.mat');
userInput = input('input a value from 1-5')
DayReport = sum(matrix(:,2)==userInput)
```

Comment: I guess its the semi-colon (`;`) inside the call to `sum`. Also, what is the `2` right before it doing?

Comment: I'm voting to close your post due to a simple typographical error.  The removal of the semi-colon will allow your code to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon and the `end` statement in the last line of code.  My guess is that you want to access the second column of `matrix`, and with that it's just `matrix(:,2)`.

Also, I suspect that you copied and pasted the code from somewhere.  That's generally bad programming practice because where you copied the code from may work in that situation, but if you try and bring it into your current context, it may be slightly different than what you're actually doing and can result in errors.

See this good discussion on Programmers Stack Exchange on why you should avoid this all together: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87696/is-copy-paste-programming-bad